# Type-safe Builder Library for Scala and Java

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

Below is a type-safe, fluid, builder pattern in Scala as described at http://www.tikalk.com/java/blog/type-safe-builder-scala-using-type-constraints. It's similar to [Builder Library for Scala and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337444/builder-library-for-scala-and-java), but deals specifically with compile-time builder checks. How can this called from Java? Can it be done with a clean API for Scala *AND* Java given the "scala.Predef$$eq$colon$eq" parameters?

```
sealed trait TBoolean
sealed trait TTrue extends TBoolean
sealed trait TFalse extends TBoolean

class Builder[HasProperty <: TBoolean] private(i: Int) {
  protected def this() = this(-1)
  def withProperty(i: Int)(implicit ev: HasProperty =:= TFalse) = new Builder[TTrue](i)
  def build(implicit ev: HasProperty =:= TTrue) = println(i)
}

//javap output
    public class Builder extends java.lang.Object implements scala.ScalaObject{
    public Builder withProperty(int, scala.Predef$$eq$colon$eq); //How is this called from Java?
    public void build(scala.Predef$$eq$colon$eq);
    public Builder();
}
object Builder {
  def apply() = new Builder[TFalse]
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use this API from Java, with some extra noise compared to the Scala version. A few convenience fields will quiet things a bit:

```
object Builder {
   def apply() = new Builder[TFalse]
   val unassigned = =:=.tpEquals[TFalse]
   val assigned = =:=.tpEquals[TTrue] 
}
```

The Java client code should end up looking like

```
Builder$.MODULE$.apply()
   .withProperty(10, Builder$.MODULE$.unassigned())
   .build(Builder$.MODULE$.assigned());
```

The `build` method has to check that every property is assigned, so it gets pretty noisy when you generalize to multiple properties:

```
Builder$.MODULE$.apply()
   .withProp1(10, Builder$.MODULE$.unassigned())
   .withProp2(20, Builder$.MODULE$.unassigned())
   .withProp3(30, Builder$.MODULE$.unassigned())
   // ...
   .build(Builder$.MODULE$.assigned(), 
          Builder$.MODULE$.assigned(), 
          Builder$.MODULE$.assigned(), 
          //...
         );
```

With some static delegates in a helper class (and some static imports), you should be able to get this down to something like:

```
createBuilder()
   .withProp1(10, unassigned())
   .withProp2(20, unassigned())
   .build(assigned(), assigned());
```

Comment: Yes, pretty noisy in Java but answers the question. May sacrifice type safety in Java version...but perhaps the @Bridge be used to provide a Java-only version and remove the *assigned() params?

Comment: Using a bridge method that passes `null`, as ittayd suggested (http://www.tikalk.com/incubator/blog/creating-java-api-scala-using-bridge#comments), will work, but it definitely sacrifices type safety.  This is because `null` is an instance of the contradiction: `TFalse =:= TTrue`.

Comment: I should also point out that the type safety of this builder pattern does not rely on implicit search.  Rather, it relies on the fact that it's impossible to instantiate the `=:=` class with two unequal type arguments (i.e. `null` is the only contradiction).

Answer (score 3):

OK, thanks to Aaron and ittayd...here is a builder with a fluid API for Scala and Java:

```
import annotation.bridge

sealed trait TBoolean
sealed trait TTrue extends TBoolean
sealed trait TFalse extends TBoolean

class Builder[HasProperty <: TBoolean] private(i: Int) {
  protected def this() = this(-1)

  def withProperty(i: Int)(implicit ev: HasProperty =:= TFalse) = new Builder[TTrue](i)
  def build(implicit ev: HasProperty =:= TTrue):Int = i
  @bridge def withProperty(i: Int) = new Builder[TTrue](i)
  @bridge def build = build(null)
}

object Builder {
  def apply() = new Builder[TFalse]
  val unassigned = =:=.tpEquals[TFalse]
  val assigned = =:=.tpEquals[TTrue]
}
```

Scala Usage (Type Safe):

```
val v = Builder().withProperty(2).build
```

Java Usage I (type safe, but ugly):

```
int i = Builder$.MODULE$.apply()
        .withProperty(5, Builder$.MODULE$.unassigned())
         .build(Builder$.MODULE$.assigned());
```

Java Usage II (not type safe, but much cleaner, using @Bridge calls):

```
static Builder createBuilder() {
  return Builder$.MODULE$.apply();
}
...
int j = createBuilder().withProperty(7).build();
```